# Transferring MySQL Workbench to Server

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-workbench

I am trying to move my database model from mysql workbench to mysql server. I am using the reverse engineer sql create script but when importing it gives me an error. I have tried to google the problem but no luck to my situation.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `MapLibrary`.`Books`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Books` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Books` (
  `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_publication` INT NULL,
  `book_title` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ISBN`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `MapLibrary`.`Genre`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Genre` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Genre` (
  `genre_code` INT NOT NULL,
  `genre_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`genre_code`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `MapLibrary`.`Books_By_Genre`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Books_By_Genre` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Books_By_Genre` (
  `genre_code` INT NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`genre_code`, `ISBN`),
  INDEX `Books_idx` (`ISBN` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `Books`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ISBN`)
    REFERENCES `MapLibrary`.`Books` (`ISBN`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Genre`
    FOREIGN KEY (`genre_code`)
    REFERENCES `MapLibrary`.`Genre` (`genre_code`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR 1022 (23000) at line 89: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'books_by_genre'

Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

Comment: What does line 82 point to? I can't count here :)

Comment: Now, please delete all non related tables. We need the table which is around the line 82 and the one linked to it. (Or the foreign key constraint and the two tables referenced in it). As a quick tip: check the data types (including the signed/unsigned flag).

Comment: @AhmadHosny It points to the Create Table Books

Comment: Checked that all datatypes are the same

Comment: Isn't the "Reverse Engineer" option the way to create a model from an existing schema? I have copied the above SQL & run it on my copy of MySQL Workbench (v6.1.7.11891 build 1788) & SQL Server 5.6.12 without any errors reported. Have you also tried the "Synchronize Model" or "Synchronize With Any Source" options - though they don't add data.

Comment: Next time please remove the noise. Most of the lines have nothing to do with the error message.

Comment: @Pred Removed all clutter unrelated. Gives me a new error now

Comment: Yeah, you removed your original question, and now you have a new question. Nope, I am out at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ISBN is NOT a unique identifier on its own in the referenced tables.

I assume, that the Books table is your base table and the three referenced tables are M:N link tables. If this is true, then your foreign keys are pointing in the wrong direction. (Try to drag the connection in the other direction?)

Comment: Id give that a try quickly

Comment: It is not about tries. The BooksByAuthor table should have a reference to the Books and the Author table. At least this is what makes sense. I have no idea how to do it in a GUI, I am a scripting guy.

Comment: I swopped the forein keys around, so that the Books_By.... Tables points to the Books table and the Pub/Auth/Genr tables. Now it is giving an different error of ERROR 1022 (23000) at line 89: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'books_by_genre' Operation failed with exitcode 1... The line shows: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MapLibrary`.`Books_By_Genre`

Comment: Nope, I won't guess whats wrong.. If this is a database designed by you (for an assigment maybe), then I should suggest to go back to your notes and try to understand how the constraints work and how to design tables for specific scenarios. You have no data in your question, you can't even create your database, how the hell you got data now? Did you change the PK constraint? Please stop using a gui if you have no idea what it does in the background. Grab a sql console and create your tables manually.